# Делаю текст более центрированным и жирным в footer, но это не помогает. Почему?

Tags: html

Хочу сделать текст более центрированным и жирным в конце css кода, но это не проходит. Почему?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>
  header {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: #ecc30b;
    color: #050505;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
</style>
<header>
  <p>Для себя</p>
</header>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>Фамилия</h1>
    <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Введите фамилию">
    <h2>Имя</h2>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <h3>Отчество</h3>
    <input type="text" id="patronymic" placeholder="Введите отчество">
    <h4>Телефон
      <h4>
        <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон">
        <div>
          <h5>Ваше обращение</h5>
          <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button id="button">Отправить</button>
  </main>
</body>

<footer>
  <p>Шишенко Антон</p>
</footer>

</html>
```

[image: Вот как это выглядит (Без бд)]

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы было более жирнее. (В footer)

Comment: Что насчёт добавить *font-weight: bold;* для тэга *footer*?

Comment: То что надо, Огромное Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавление font-weight: bold; в style.css

```
<style>
font-weight:bold;
</style>
```